# django - multiplication and templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I hope you can help me on this one. I have a template that shows the price of a, lets say a Banana, and for example the banana costs $400 and i have to calculate the 21% of this price and show it on a box of a table. I was tempted to do something like:

```
{% for banana in bananas %}
{{banana.price}}*(21%)
{% endfor %}
```

but obviously that failed miserably.

So, is there a way to do this type of simple equations in a template or i need to make a custom template tag to handle it.

its a very basic question but i would really appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do need a custom template tag, but you could install [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters), which provides such basic operations:

```
{% load mathfilters %}

...

{{banana.price|mul:0.21}}
```

Taken from the mathfilters page, the included operations are:

- sub – subtraction
- mul – multiplication
- div – division
- abs – absolute value
- mod – modulo

'Add' is provided in Django as standard.

Comment: I have a question about this. Im gettin the price of the banana:
{{banana.price|mul:0.21}}
now i want to add this number that i just recived from this multiplication to another number (banana + (result of the multiplication)) and i want to show it in another box of the table
any idea of how to do this?

Comment: You'd definitely have to write your own custom template tag. If you have several operations to perform on variables, it might be better to do so within your views.py though. Then in the template itself restrict yourself to simple operations of the format 'variable*constant', (such as 'banana*0.21'). This will save you writing a lot of custom tags and cluttering up the template code.

Comment: you mean doing the multiplications and addings in the views and then pass everything to the template?

Comment: Generally, yes. If all you had to do was a quick multiplication by 0.21, then it could go in the template. But when you have to start writing custom template tags, it's better to do as much as you can in views.py. Remember that if you have to re-format this code in the future (government taxes change, you start charging more for shipping, etc), it's usually much easier to edit views.py, rather than looking through a bunch of custom template tags and changing them. So it's generally a good idea to keep the view functionality and the template separate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in [`widthratio`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio) template tag:

> For creating bar charts and such, this tag calculates the ratio of a
>   given value to a maximum value, and then applies that ratio to a
>   constant.

```
{% widthratio banana.price 100 21 %}
```